# Why x86 apps cannot run on ARM processors?

Tags: linux, windows, arm

In computers, the kernel sits between the application and the hardware (CPU) and it allows the software to interact with hardware.

So on the Microsoft Surface X (SQ1 and SQ2 processor), why can't developers bring over their applications from the x86 Windows? e.g. Chrome, Firefox, some benchmark tools and games... I thought Microsoft only need to replace their x86-64 kernel with the ARM version and most applications will work fine.

Same goes for Linux.

Comment: each hardware platform uses a different ISA with different instructions and instruction encoding, which is like different human languages. x86 hardware speaks x86 language, ARM software is written in ARM language, how can they understand x86 understands ARM and vice versa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, the kernel does less than you expect it does. In particular, the kernel does not translate/parse/interpret/mangle the machine code a compiled binary is made of.

when someone [compiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) source code into a binary, what they are doing is really translating that source code into [machine code instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) that the CPU understands.

One of the things that makes [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) a platform, is a shared [Instruction Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) across all compatible hardware. That way, a compiler can expect that any x86 CPU will understand the `PUSH` instruction and do the expected thing when you execute it via a thread.

[ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) uses a different instruction set. In this case, the source code needs to be compiled (translated) into instructions an ARM CPU can understand (instructions defined in it's instruction set).

Not all programs use "native" binaries (binaries that consist exclusively of well formed instructions that are implemented by the CPUs instruction set). languages like Java and C# compile to a virtual assembly language, and are JIT compiled to native instructions at runtime. Others use interpreters that have been customized for a given platform.

So in sum, ARM CPUs do not recognize the language that x86 compiled programs use and vice versa. While the Kernel will control things like hardware access and CPU scheduling, it does not change the instructions of the programs executing on the system.  it just creates the process, kicks off execution, and grants execution time on the CPU, so that many processes can share it semi-simultaneously.

Comment: It is possible for an OS to have a built-in emulator or translator for other architectures – like how macOS has had Rosetta through its PPC-x64-ARM journey, and Windows itself *used to have* x86 emulation back when it used to run on Alpha CPUs – but it takes quite a bit more than just the kernel alone.

Comment: indeed. until (what feels like) just a few years ago, Windows emulated all 16-bit DOS applications. IIRC that's the perhaps the key distinction between the VDM and the native command shell. That said, like all emulation, you can only really expect it to work well if the actual system sufficiently exceeds the native environment of system being emulated.